# Use Variable in StringContent

Tags: c#, json, string

Is it possible to have a variable in `StringContent`?

Currently my Code looks like this (It's about `\"text\": \"this is my message\"`):

```
myRequestMessage.Content = new StringContent("{\"type\": \"message\", \"text\": \"this is my message\", \"from\": {\"id\": \"myID\", \"name\": \"myName\"}}", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

But I want to have it like this (`\"text\": "+myOwnString+"`):

```
myOwnString = "this is my text";
myRequestMessage.Content = new StringContent("{\"type\": \"message\", \"text\": "+myOwnString+", \"from\": {\"id\": \"myID\", \"name\": \"myName\"}}", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

My problem is when doing it like I want to have it I get a `StatusCode 400, ReasonPhrase: Bad Request` from `var myResponse = await myClient.SendAsync(myRequestMessage);`. So I assume I have to write it differently to make it work.

Does anyone know a fix?

Comment: You still need to wrap the string you provide in double-quotes for it to be valid json. So `\"text\": \"" + myOwnString + "\"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you are missing the quotes around the text that you concatenated.

Try this:

```
myRequestMessage.Content = new StringContent("{\"type\": \"message\", \"text\": \""+myOwnString+"\", \"from\": {\"id\": \"myID\", \"name\": \"myName\"}}", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

Answer (score 5):

This kind of operation becomes much easier, more readable and robust if you serialize an anonymous type instead of using concatenation:

```cs
var output = new {
    type = "message",
    text = "this is any message you want it to be",
    from = new {
            id = "myId",
            name = "myName"
    }
};

var outputJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(output);
```

Result:

```js
{
  "type": "message",
  "text": "this is any message you want it to be",
  "from": {
    "id": "myId",
    "name": "myName"
  }
}
```